# Is there a better alternative to Thread.Sleep when waiting for data to change using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

I have an database I access using Entity Framework and a set of actions that I need to execute in order on remote machines. The machines communicate when they're done by updating the database and don't report back otherwise. Given the architecture of the rest of the code, providing some event that I can hook into would be difficult (although that would be ideal). An example of what I'm attempting to do is:

```
private enum Machines
{
    SetA,
    SetB
};

private void Action()
{
    ExecuteWork(Machines.SetA);
    while (!IsWorkDone(Machines.SetA))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
    ExecuteWork(Machines.SetB);
}

private void ExecuteWork(Machines machineGroup)
{
    // Do long running work on every remote machine in this set, between 10-40 minutes.
    // When this work is completed, each machine reports its completion to a database.
}
```

Is there a better way to hold off executing the next action until the first action has finished if the limitation is that we have to rely on the database for the status update to go ahead?

```
private bool IsWorkDone(Machines machineGroup)
{
    using (_context = new DbContext())
    {
        var machines = _context.Machines.Where(machine => machine.Group.Equals(machineGroup.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        foreach (var machine in machines)
        {
            if (machine.Status == Status.Incomplete)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entity Framework is ***not*** a database - it's a **database access** technology with which you can access a database and get data from it. EF supports **various** databases - but it's not a database itself

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database-as-IPC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using `async`, `await`, and `Task` for this. Without to much work, you can change your `Action()` function to be:

```
private async Task Action()
{
    ExecuteWork(Machines.SetA);
    while (!IsWorkDone(Machines.SetA))
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }
    ExecuteWork(Machines.SetB);
}
```

While this still waits for `ExecuteWork()` to complete, it does so in a non blocking way. So the code that would call `Action()` would then look like:

```
//does not have to be async
private async Task Test()
{
    //Action will execute until it hits the await Task.Delay(),
    //at which point, execution will return to this function
    //(if Test() is marked async) until the time span is up.
    Task t = Action();
    //If Test() is not async, I believe that Action() will run
    //on a separate thread, but I may be wrong.

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        console.log(i);
    }

    //At this point, execution of Test() will stop until
    //Action() finnishes, and the calling function will continue if it 
    //has the async modifier.
    await t;
}
```

If the function was not marked `async Task`, but simply `void`, you would wait for t to complete by using `t.Wait()`.

Comment: Excellent answer, this is exactly what I was looking for.